# Iterating Through Sequential Nested Classes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to iterate through table cells with classes `row[i]` for the rows and `col[i]` for the columns. However, this is currently not working:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
        $(".row[" + i + "] .col[" + j + "]").html('1');
    }
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/A4HvP/1/

Comment: good idea but im wondering if row[i] is a valid classname

Comment: `$(".row[" + 1 + "] .col[" + 1 + "]").html('1');` searches for a element with class `row` and attribute `1` and a child with class `col` and attribute `1`

Comment: Not judging this approach, but I would suggest to rename classes to `row_#` and `col_#` to avoid this issue with `[]`

Comment: Here I tried using `row-i` `col-i` naming instead, but it didn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/GyZQ5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping `[` with `\[`

```
$(".row\\[" + i + "\\] .col\\[" + j + "\\]").html('1');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D6L6w/)

As an alternate I would suggest naming the classes like `row-1` instead of `row[1]`

then

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
        $(".row-" + i + " .col-" + j).html('1');
    }
}
```

`$(".row[" + 1 + "] .col[" + 1 + "]").html('1');` searches for a element with class `row` and attribute `1` and a child with class `col` and attribute `1`

like

```
<tr class="row" 1>
    <td class="cell" 1></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried changing it to .row-1 .col-1 too, in this one example: http://jsfiddle.net/GyZQ5/ It still doesn't do anything

Comment: @Jamil you missed to include jQuery library in the fiddle - in left hand panel first select box select jQuery - see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fucua/1/

Comment: I see. The escaping or otherwise changing the name convention was it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
   for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
     //iterate through columns
     //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should explain what is "not working".

However, it might be that javascript arrays are zero based NOT one based.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { ... }
```

Comment: I added a fiddle to demonstrate (in the question). It's the name of the class, so I don't think that should be a problem.